# How to create a report when there are five relationship objects?

Tags: apex, reporting, custom-reports, joined-reports

[image]

I have 5 Objects and they have a relationship with each other as shown above. Now I need to create a report to Object E values based on the condition of object A, B, C, D

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to create a [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_report_type_setup.htm&type=0). It sounds to me like what you need is a report type with the primary object being E. You'd then use [*Add fields related via lookup*](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&type=0) to bring in field details from objects A, B, C, and D. Four is the limit on object relationships in a custom report type.

This report type would then allow you to create a report on *E*s and filter by fields from all four parent objects.